# How do I switch tf.train.Optimizers during training?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I want to switch from [Adam](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer) to [SGD](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer) after a certain number of epochs. How do I do this smoothly so that the weights/gradients are passed over to the new optimizer?

Comment: please add some code or show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Just define two optimizers and switch between them:

```
sgd_optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
adap_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
...
for epoch in range(100):
  for (x, y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
    optimizer = sgd_optimizer if epoch > 50 else adap_optimizer
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
```

An optimizer only encapsulates the way to apply the gradients to the tensors, and may hold just a few own variables. The model weights are not stored in the optimizers, so you can switch them easily.