# how can I change tensorflow optimizer during training

Tags: tensorflow

I read before that sgd generalize better but adam converge fast in early stage of training.
So, I want to change my optimizer after some steps. But code like below raised preconditionederror. If anyone knows how can I change optimizer during training?

```
for i in range(config.train_steps):
    _, l, s = sess.run([train_op, loss, summary])

    if i % 100 == 0:
        saver.save(sess, os.path.join(args.model_dir,
                                          'model.ckpt'))
        writer.add_summary(s, i)
        print('loss: ', l)
    if i == 1000:
        train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46851064/712995

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I switch tf.train.Optimizers during training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850835/how-do-i-switch-tf-train-optimizers-during-training)

Comment: @Maxim sorry you are right. Why could I find this question before...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change an optimizer as such, but you can create two optimizers and use one first and the other second. That is basically what you are doing in your code. The problem is that optimizers frequently have some internal variables associated which you need to initialize, like any other, before being able to use it. Also, your code is not fully correct anyway, because you have not called the `minimize` operation. Try instead something like this:

```
early_train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
late_train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
# Call this after everything, including optimizers, has been created
init_op = tf.initialize_global_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)  # Now everything is correctly initialized
    for i in range(config.train_steps):
        if i < 1000:
            current_train_op = early_train_op
        else:
            current_train_op = late_train_op

        _, l, s = sess.run([current_train_op, loss, summary])

        if i % 100 == 0:
            saver.save(sess, os.path.join(args.model_dir,
                                          'model.ckpt'))
            writer.add_summary(s, i)
            print('loss: ', l)
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: I'll try that. In fact, I used tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss in order to get train operation. I just want to show that how I tried to change operation during training. Anyway, It's my fault. Thanks!!